# Drawing SVG images in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, image, svg, wxwidgets

I need to be able to draw [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) images (with the ability to scale, and rotate the images by 90,180 and 270 degrees).

I also want the ability of instead of rendering the images to a bitmap (e.g. for displaying), to be able to draw them into a new SVG image (exporting the "document" to SVG).

wxWidgets does not seem to have any built in SVG capabilities, so I'm not sure how to proceed on adding such functionality.

Comment: Small note. Know the limitations of SVG. I once wrote a program to create a massive bounce diagram with dozens of agents talking to each other based on parsing a simulation log file, only to find out that SVG is very slow in Firefox and IE when you create large SVG files. I changed to drawing my stuff on a QT canvas, and it ran with no problems. ( I realize QT/wxWidgets doesn't embed in the browser so this may not work for your case.)

Comment: Well im writing a desktop application, although you know of an alternative vector graphics format which i can use in wxWidgets and has good support in image editing software im open to suggestions.

Comment: +1 For including a link to explain *SVG*.

Answer (score 6):

The [cairo library website](http://www.cairographics.org/) has [examples](http://www.cairographics.org/examples/) on drawing SVG using [librsvg](http://librsvg.sourceforge.net/).

Both the *cairo* and *librsvg* libraries should be sufficiently cross-platform to do what you need, and with [wxcairo](http://code.google.com/p/wxcairo/) it should be possible to dock them onto *wxWidgets*.

That is the first idea I would research when faced with the task of drawing SVG into *wxWidgets*.

Also, drawing to SVG files with *cairo* is quite easy when you are doing all your drawing with *cairo* anyway, and the drawing model *cairo* uses is quite similar to SVG.

Answer (score 2):

You can render into a file in SVG format using wxSVGFileDC (http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_s_v_g_file_d_c.html) but there is no support for drawing SVG images, you will need to use an SVG rendering library and integrate it with wx (how to do this is platform-dependent).

Notice that wxSVGFileDC is in contrib, i.e. an additional library which needs to be built independently, in wx 2.8 but is in the main library itself in 2.9.